# Slow update query in mysql with left join

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I ran into an performance issue when I use `left join` in an `update` query. When I pass one argument to `IN` my query is slow, but when I pass several arguments my query is much faster.

```
UPDATE deliverables
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT deliverable_id, SUM(value) as sum_value
  FROM deliverable_imputations
  GROUP BY deliverable_id
) deliverable_imputations_join ON deliverables.id = deliverable_imputations_join.deliverable_id
SET deliverables.value = deliverable_imputations_join.sum_value
WHERE deliverables.id IN (28450)

+------+-------------+-------------------------+-------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------+---------+-------+--------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table                   | type  | possible_keys | key                                             | key_len | ref   | rows   | Extra       |
+------+-------------+-------------------------+-------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------+---------+-------+--------+-------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY     | deliverables            | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY                                         | 4       | const | 1      |             |
|    1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>              | ALL   | NULL          | NULL                                            | NULL    | NULL  | 136698 | Using where |
|    2 | DERIVED     | deliverable_imputations | index | NULL          | index_deliverable_imputations_on_deliverable_id | 5       | NULL  | 136698 |             |
+------+-------------+-------------------------+-------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------+---------+-------+--------+-------------+
```

=> **0.254 sec**

```
UPDATE deliverables
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT deliverable_id, SUM(value) as sum_value
    FROM deliverable_imputations
    GROUP BY deliverable_id
  ) deliverable_imputations_join ON deliverables.id = deliverable_imputations_join.deliverable_id
  SET deliverables.value = deliverable_imputations_join.sum_value
  WHERE deliverables.id IN (28450, null)

+------+-----------------+-------------------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+---------+---------------------------+------+-------------+
| id   | select_type     | table                   | type  | possible_keys                                   | key                                             | key_len | ref                       | rows | Extra       |
+------+-----------------+-------------------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+---------+---------------------------+------+-------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY         | deliverables            | range | PRIMARY                                         | PRIMARY                                         | 4       | NULL                      | 1    | Using where |
|    1 | PRIMARY         | <derived2>              | ref   | key0                                            | key0                                            | 5       | cesar_dev.deliverables.id | 2    |             |
|    2 | LATERAL DERIVED | deliverable_imputations | ref   | index_deliverable_imputations_on_deliverable_id | index_deliverable_imputations_on_deliverable_id | 5       | cesar_dev.deliverables.id | 13   |             |
+------+-----------------+-------------------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+---------+---------------------------+------+-------------+
```

=> **0.001 sec**

I have similar behavior with `WHERE deliverables.id = 28450` and `WHERE deliverables.id = 28450 OR deliverables.id IS NULL`. I can replace `null` by any others ids.

I am curious about the explanation behind that behavior.

Comment: Have you checked the plans? What is the point of the `left join` anyway here?

Comment: Add `WHERE deliverable_id IN (28450)` inside the subquery, too

Comment: @Akina (after they edited) we can see it is used in the `SET` clause. I guess they had a dumbed down query before.

Comment: It seems to be doing the grouping for everything but then using only the data for 28450.  Rewrite the query to simplify it.

Comment: Which version of MySQL/MariaDB are you using?

Comment: MariaDB 15.1 in development, but same issue with a Percona Server in production. With your's and @ypercubeᵀᴹ's comment, I get the point about making a too big subquery but I don't understand why adding a second id to the IN reduce the scope of the subquery.